# Маленькая проблема в системе подписки django

Tags: python, django

Хочу сделать систему подписок в сайте но плохо работает

мои коды

models

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='imageusers', verbose_name='Изображение')
infouser = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=5)
placework = models.TextField(default='Отсутствует')
city = models.TextField(default='Отсутствует')
activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, 
            related_name='is_following',
            blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
class UserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Данные пользователя'

    # Определяем новый класс настроек для модели User
    class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
        inlines = (UserInline, )

    # Перерегистрируем модель User
    admin.site.unregister(User)
    admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

views.py

Это когда заходиш в другим в гости

```
def userdetail(request, id=None):
userobj = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, id=id)


initial_data = {
    "object_id": userobj.id,
}

context = {
    "userobj": userobj,
}
return render(request, 'accounts/kabdetail.html', context)
```

А это сам профиль

```
def kabinet(request):
formimg = Createimg(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
if formimg.is_valid():
    ins = formimg.save(commit=False)
    ins.user = request.user
    ins.save()
    return redirect("/kabinet/")
context = {
    "forming": formimg,
}

return render(request, 'accounts/kabinet.html', context)
```

Вот с помощью такой функции или метода хочу реализовать это

```
class ProfileFollowToggle(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_to_toggle = request.POST.get("username")
        profile_ = 
        UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact=user_to_toggle)
        user = request.user
        if user in profile_.followers.all():
            profile_.followers.remove(user)
        else:
            profile_.followers.add(user)

        profile_.save()
        return redirect("/kabinet/kablist/")
```

А вот шаблоны и кнопка подписки

Кнопка подписки

```
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
<form class='form' method='POST' action='{% url "follow" %}'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type='hidden' name='username' 
 value='{% if username %}{{ username }}{% else %}notusername{% endif %}'>

<button class="btn {% if user.userprofile in request.user.is_following.all %}btn-default{% else %}btn-primary
{% endif %}">
{% if user.userprofile in request.user.is_following.all %}Отписаться
{% else %}Подписаться{% endif %}

</button>

</form>
{% endif %}
```

шаблон профиль человека на который заходиш в гости

```
    <p>{{ user.is_following.count }}</p>

{% if user.userprofile in request.user.is_following.all %}
    Is Following
{% endif %}
<p>{% include 'accounts/snippet/follow_form.html' with username=user.username is_following=is_following %}</p>
```

А это профиль

```
<p>{{ user.userprofile.followers.count }}</p>
      <p>{{ user.userprofile.followers.all }}</p>
```

Comment: А в чем у вас собственно вопрос? Как именно должно работать? Какой результат хотите получить на выходе? Какие  ошибки выдаются (если есть) ?

Comment: вроде работает добавляется число подписчиков но в базе данных нечего не происходит и не сохраняются в manytomanyfield не добавляются подписчики

Comment: и шаблоне вроде не правильно показывает число

Comment: и еше вроде я нажимаю подписаться а подписчики добавляются у меня а не у них